# Use VLOOKUP in a dynamic range using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to set up VB so I can do a VLOOKUP on a dynamic range of values. It'll always start at the same place, but it may end further down based on whatever value is in H4.

EDIT: Here's the code and it works.

Thank you Alex!

```
Public Sub State()

    Dim refRng As Range, ref As Range, dataRng As Range
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim count As Integer
    i = Sheet2.Range("H1").Value
    i = i + 3 'offset of when to start

    Set refRng = Sheet2.Range("D8:" & Cells(8, i).Address) '//horizontal range of look up values
    Set dataRng = Sheet13.Range("A:C") '//data block you want to look up value in

    For Each ref In refRng
    ref.Offset(1, 0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(refRng, dataRng, 2, True)
    Next ref
End Sub
```

Comment: What does WorksheetFunction.VLookup return? and what is ref.Offset do? I thought ref was where my output would go but it doesn't seem like that's the case when I'm playing with it.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what your data looks like, and what you expect to get with some sample inputs.

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.VlookUp` returns the value you are trying to find based on values in row starting at `D8`. `Offset` just puts the returned value the row below `D8` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help:

```
Sub LookUp()
    Dim refRng As Range, ref As Range, dataRng As Range

    Set refRng = Worksheets(1).Range("D8:F8") //horizontal range of look up values
    Set dataRng = Worksheets(2).Range("A1:B4") //data block you want to look up value in

    For Each ref In refRng
        ref.Offset(1, 0) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ref, dataRng, 2, 0)
    Next ref
End Sub
```

Here you set up references to your lookup values and the data you want to query. Then just iterate over the values in the horizontal range and look up the value.

Comment: What if I'm figuring the range dynamically? Based on the count in H4?