# Vlookup Range of a counter Value

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, vlookup

I'm trying to do a Vlookup an the defined range is the counter value of the For:

```
For N2 = 4 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Range("B3").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP($B5,'[" & N2 & "]'!$B$4:$AH$35,MATCH(C$3,'[" & N2 & "]'!$B$3:$AH$3,0),FALSE)"
Next N2
```

But the '[" & N & "]' asks me to open the "3" file but I want to do the vlookup in the Worksheet number 3

Could you please help me to correct that part?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
For N2 = 4 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
Range("B3").End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP($B5,'Sheet" & N2 & "'!$B$4:$AH$35,MATCH(C$3,'Sheet" & N2 & "'!$B$3:$AH$3,0),FALSE)"
Next N2
```

Comment: your code seems to be correct but you have to add correct sheet name, if sheet unable to find then only its asks for open the correct workbook which has that sheet. So make sure you are adding the correct sheet name

Comment: I understand but how is the proper way to write the range value in the formula so when is doing the vlookup it searches in the sheet that has the N2 value for example 3 is the N2 value

Comment: for dynamic range you can use worksheetfunction.vlookup.             please refer this      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473197/use-vlookup-in-a-dynamic-range-using-vba

Comment: I've checked that one but that code is with a defined colum and I'm using Match to bring the column I'm searching.

Comment: Can you elaborate how and why this code can help to resolve the OP issue?

Comment: ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(B2, '[" & GEII Aqua Payroll Register 2015 & ".xlsm]" & sheetsource & "'!$B$4:$AH$34, MATCH(cell3,'[" & GEII Aqua Payroll Register 2015 & ".xlsm]" & sheetsource & "'!$B$3:$AH$3,0),FALSE)" Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?